# Fixing wrongly character encoded files with iconv

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, iconv

I have several hundred txt files that have lost their correct encoding between OS / external hard drives. I am trying to convert them back with iconv but can't figure out how to fix the encoding.

Might be worth mentioning that I am on MacOS and using the Node.js package: `iconv-lite`.

What I've tried:

Decoding (reading the file) -> Encoding (writing back to):

```
UTF-8 -> UTF-16 / 32

UTF-8 -> ISO-8859-1 / ISO-8859-1

ISO-8859-1 / 7 -> UTF-8
```

Examples of wrong encodings:

Wrong -> Correct:

```
Ê -> æ 

¯ -> ø
```

But it's not just a single language. The original encoding might very well have been Japanese but opening the files it says that it's UTF-8 so I don't know what it originally was.

How do I fix the encoding issues. What should it be read as, written as? How do I avoid that this will ever happen again?

Comment: `utf-8` is the only and the same on all platforms. For your given [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) examples (using Python): `'Ê¯'.encode('mac_roman') == 'æø'.encode('cp1252')` returns `True` and `'Ê¯'.encode('mac_roman').decode('cp1252')` returns `'æø'`.

Comment: @JosefZ I've never heard of Mojibake but that's exactly it. I'm amazed you were able to find the right encoding. Apparently Iconv does not support these so I'm glad to have resolved it easily with Python.